# android monitor throw E/HW-JPEG-DEC after update to android 7

Tags: java, android

after update phone to android 7 when i build app again Android Monitor throw error:

> E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was face this problem and some of the design on my app didn't appear,

after long search I found the problem and it was with scrollView rotate attribute,

So if you use any scrollView or autoScrollViewPager or gridView or any type of view that using scroll, please check if you use any attribute that related to rotation or direction for the scrollView like android:rotateY = "180".

instead of using this, try to use android:scaleX="-1".

This help me to fix my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using a logcat filter helped me in hiding this log. The Log Tag Regex is `^(?!.*(HW-JPEG-DEC)).*$`.

Answer (score 1):

Your resource images most likely contain meta/exif data that is not properly handled by the built-in image viewer. You may either ignore those errors or remove the meta data from your images.